# How to convert OAuth code with an access token

Tags: oauth

Imagine you're going through a standard OAuth2 process to retrieve an `access_token` for some third-party API. This is the usual process.

1. User is redirected to `http://some-service.com/login`
2. User successfully logs in and is redirected to some destination `http://some-destination.com`. In this step, there's usually a `code` parameter that comes with the request. So the actual URL looks like `http://some-destination.com?code=CODE123`
3. I need to use `CODE123` to request an `access_token` that can be used to authorize my future API calls. To do this, there's an endpoint that usually looks like this (I am using Nylas as an example but should be generic enough):

[image]

As you can see, it requires me to POST the code from above (`CODE123`) along with `client_id` and `client_secret` like this: `http://some-service.com/oauth/token?code=CODE123&client_secret=SECRET&client_id=ID`. As a response, I get an `access_token` that looks like `TOKEN123` and I can use this to make API calls.

**QUESTION**

Until step 2, everything happens in the client side. But in step 3, I need to have `client_id` and `client_secret`. I don't think it's a good idea to store these values in the client side. Does that mean I need to have a backend server that has these two values, and my backend should convert `CODE123` to `TOKEN123` and hand it to the client side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you probably know, the question describes the most common (and usually, the more secure) OAuth ["Authorization Code" flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1). To be clear, here's an approximation of the steps in this flow:

1. User indicates that they wish to authorize resources for our application (for example, by clicking on a button)
2. The application redirects the user to the third-party login page, where the user logs in and selects which resources to grant access to
3. The third-party service redirects the user back to our application with an *authorization code*
4. Our application uses this code, along with its client ID and secret to obtain an *access token* that enables the application to make requests on behalf of the user only for the resources that the user allowed

> Until step 2, everything happens in the client side. But in step 3, I need to have client_id and client_secret. I don't think it's a good idea to store these values in the client side. Does that mean I need to have a backend server that has these two values[?]

You're correct, it's certainly *not* a good idea to store these values in the client-side application. These values—especially the client secret—*must* be placed on a server to protect the application's data. The user—and therefor, the client application—should never have access to these values.

The server uses its client ID and secret, along with the authorization code, to request an access token that it uses for API calls. The server may store the token it receives, along with an optional *refresh token* that it can use in the future to obtain a new access token without needing the user to explicitly authorize access again.

> ...and my backend should convert CODE123 to TOKEN123 and hand it to the client side?

At the very least, our server should handle the authorization flow to request an access token, and then pass only that token back to the client (over a secure connection).

However, at this point, the client-side application (and the user of that client) is responsible for the security of the access token. Depending on the security requirements of our application, we may want to add a layer to protect this access token from the client as well.

After the server-side application fetches the access token from the third-party service, if we pass the access token back to the client, malware running on the client machine, or an unauthorized person, could potentially obtain the access token from the client, which an attacker could then use to retrieve or manipulate the user's third-party resources through privileges granted to *our* application. For many OAuth services, *an access token is not associated with a client*. This means that anyone with a valid token can use the token to interact with the service, and illustrates why our application should only request the minimum scope of access needed when asking for authorization from the user.

To make API calls on behalf of a user more securely, the client-side application could send requests to our server, which, in turn, uses the access token that it obtained to interact with the third-party API. With this setup, the client does not need to know the value of the access token.

To improve performance, we likely want to cache the access token on the server for subsequent API calls for the duration of its lifetime. We may also want to encrypt the tokens if we store them in the application's database—just like we would passwords—so the tokens cannot be easily used in the event of a data breach.

Comment: Thanks Cy, makes a lot of sense. I am only confused about this: "To make API calls on behalf of a user more securely, the client-side application could send requests to our server, which, in turn, uses the access token that it obtained to interact with the third-party API. With this setup, the client does not need to know the value of the access token."

If the server side holds the `access_token`, how do we authenticate/authorize the requests coming from the client to the server?

Comment: @Maximus the client needs to authenticate with the server via some trust model (such as when a user logs into the application). We can implement this auth process however we like, and it's not necessarily related to OAuth. For example, we could use server-side sessions, or generate an application-specific token for the client. Then, a compromised client can only try to exploit the third-party service within the constraints of the API that our application's exposes to the client. We'd use this extra layer if we decide that we can't trust the client with the access token...

Comment: ...which we may do if the third-party service will only give us an access token that authorizes a greater scope of access to resources than the application needs to use, for instance.

Comment: When the client asks the server for an `access_token` with a `code` param, should the server just respond with a `session_key` instead of a `access_token`? And the client can keep using the `session_key` to ask the server to make calls to the third-party service. But it does look more complicated than just using the access_token from the client side directly.

Comment: @Maximus this depends on the application. In many cases, the client may have already authenticated with the server when the user initiates the request to grant access to their third-party data. If we want to allow the user to authenticate *through* a third-party ("Sign up with Facebook"), then we'd probably pass back a session key of some sort instead of the access token to establish a trust relationship. It certainly is more complicated, as security tends to be. To be clear, this approach isn't *necessary*--we could give the client the access token, and some applications do.

Comment: Perform a risk analysis to determine the extent of damage that could occur from a compromised token based, in part, on the type of data that a token grants access to. Then, decide whether the cost of protecting the token in this way justifies the extra work and compute overhead needed for your specific application. The chance of jeopardizing a token and related data in this way is probably low, and access tokens typically expire quickly to limit the extent of damage from these incidents, but it's part of our responsibility as the stewards of a user's data to consider these implications.